# Laravel access blade variable in helper

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I have a public variable `$publisher` shared to all view:

```
$view->with('publisher', $publisher);
```

Example: I would like to check this publisher is named as 'main' and is status 'active', hence I have to write if statement in blade like this:

```
@if ($publisher->name == 'main' && $publisher->status == 'active')
    // Code here
@endif
```

It's replicated for all the blade file, therefore I created a custom helper file at `app/Helpers/general.php`, named it as `isMainPublisher($publisher)`:

```
function isMainPublisher($publisher) 
{
    return ($publisher->name == 'main' && $publisher->status == 'active') ? true: false;
}
```

The blade if statement will be changed to:

```
@if (isMainPublisher($publisher))
    // Code here
@endif
```

I am thinking to shorten the blade code to this:

```
@if (isMainPublisher())
    // Code here
@endif
```

But `app/Helpers/general.php` will not access the blade variable `$publisher`, is there anyway or actually no way to access blade variable in helper? Thanks.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but wouldn't it make more sense to have `isMain()` method on the Publisher object instead? And call it `$publisher->isMain()`. It's way more expressive. Other than that, you could have a variable `$isMainPublisher` instead of a helper and share it with all views.

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand why would they do that? If this has to do with a model, which I'm fairly certain it does, it would make more sense to add the method to the Model. Effectively, if OP needed to use the method again anywhere else, he'd have it on the model without having to re-write it. Always remember the DRY principle!

Comment: @Derek I'm totally fine with your answer but he wants `@if (isMainPublisher())` logic, so I was trying to give him exactly what he wants.

Comment: That is not feasible. How would you get the `$publisher` variable in `isMainPublisher()`?

Comment: @Momo I agree with Derek's answer.

Comment: Thanks for everyone replied, in short, there is no way to access blade template variable in declared helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, short of setting the publisher name on an internal variable of the helper class, `isMainPublisher($publisher)` is your best choice, AND its way more idiomatic than the other option.

In order to get `isMainPublisher()` to work (possibly), you would have to work with a hacky global declaration, which even then, would probably not work as it is not available to the class

**ALTERNATIVELY**, you could add the helper onto the model as a method:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Publisher extends Model
{
    // Your new helper method
    public function isMain()
    {
        // some logic to determine if the publisher is main
        return ($this->name == "main" || $this->name == "blah"); 
    }
}
```

...and then call it like this:

```
$publisher->isMain();
```

Which in my point of view, is the superior choice as it reads like you'd say it.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I agree that this is a superior choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Mike thanks @Momo No problem, will you accept it as the answer please